# Unzipping a file stored on Azure results in a file without extension

Tags: gzip, azure-worker-roles, azure-blob-storage

I've got 2 separate worker roles:

WR1 - stores a given file (pdf) in a specific container on the blob store, here's  the code:

```
var folderName = dynamicFolderNameAsInputToThisMethod;
            CloudBlobContainer container;

            container = GetCloudBlobContainerByName(containerName);

            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(string.Format("{0}/{1}", folderName, fileName));
            blob.Properties.ContentType = inThisInstanceApplicationPdf;
            await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(storageBlob.FileAsByteArray, 0, storageBlob.FileAsByteArray.Length);

            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", _blobClient.BaseUri, folderName, fileName);
```

This saves the file no problem.

The second worker role extracts the file from this as a byte array, zips it and saves is back to a different 'folder' on the blob store. This is how I get the byte array:

```
var filesInContainer = new List<byte[]>();
            var blobContainer = GetCloudBlobContainerByName(fileProcessStage);
            var blobDirectory = blobContainer.ListBlobs(
                string.Format("{0}/{1}", folderName, subFolderName))
                .FirstOrDefault(b => b is CloudBlobDirectory) as CloudBlobDirectory;

            foreach (var blob in blobDirectory.ListBlobs())
            {
                var blockBlob = blob as CloudBlockBlob;
                byte[] fileContent = new byte[blockBlob.Properties.Length];
                blockBlob.DownloadToByteArray(fileContent, 0);
                filesInContainer.Add(fileContent);
            }

            return filesInContainer;
```

Assumption: There's always 1 file in the folder when extracting.

Then compresses it using Gzip:

```
public byte[] Compress(byte[] bytesToCompress)
        {
            using(var originalStream = new MemoryStream(bytesToCompress))
            {
                using(var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        originalStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                    }

                    return compressedFileStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

Saves the byte array returned by this above method to another blob container as a 'filename.gz' file.

Everything works, however, when the gz file is downloaded and unzipped the file inside it has no extension and the user has to rename the file and give it a .pdf. The file then appears as it should.

I am unable to figure out where in the process is the file losing its extension.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a gzip just a compression of bytes with no concept of a **file**? I'm pretty sure you need to name the output `filename.ext.gz` so that when you uncompress it, you get `filename.ext`.

(the uncompressed file, named the same, minus .gz)